# How to prevent exposing primary id to UI from server?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

We have product and product-image API that we need to expose to the clients. I don't want to expose the product id's generated in our database as these are sequential id's and any attacker can easily change things. The APIs are not secured as we using these through JS and will be exposed to multiple clients.

Client hit POST API /product/ and the request body has product details.

In the response we get product uri i.e. /product/1/. Here 1 is the product id.

Further, client uses this product id i.e. to insert images like:

/product/1/images/

I am worried that we are exposing id's and these may be changed by anyone. I read [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/139450/is-obscuring-obfuscating-public-facing-database-ids-really-a-best-practice) thing. But I didn't get any clear idea what is right way to solve this in MVC context. Can we store stock_id in "session" storage OR what would be best way to solve this?

Comment: "The APIs are not secured as we using these through JS and will be exposed to multiple clients" sounds like security through obscurity - generally a bad idea. That being said, uniqueidentifier columns map to Guid in C#, and aren't sequential unless you tell the database to make them so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The client *will* have to have the id, no matter where you store it. The saying is "the client is is the hands of the enemy". The only correct way to handle this is to not care for ids but instead secure your API so that only users that are allowed to change stuff are able to do so.

Comment: How would we secure api that Will be called from web clients I.e. through JavaScript..?

Comment: May be we could send encrypted id's to the client.. and server would decrypt the same for future requests..isn't it correct? Since we are only concerned that there shouldn't be any pattern of ids to the client

Comment: You secure your API like anybody else: access control. Don't let random internet strangers call your API. Https username/password is the most primitive, you need to pick the mechanism that suits you.

Comment: If I am not wrong, this would only solve  if api is accessed from external origin.. still anyone can fiddle with these by postman etc.

Comment: Err... no? That's the *point*. You really need to read up on the basics on authentication/authorization. Get a good book or tutorial. This site is meant for very specific questions, you seem to be missing a good part of the concept. That's not bad, but you need to read up on it.

Comment: Any good article,book,tutorial that could help us secure these APIs quickly. May not be full proof but quick to implement. We need to urgently do this

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your problem correctly, the current process is as follows:

1. Client requests product overview
2. Client receives a list with the products and their IDs
3. Client can open product details
4. Client can use the ID to insert images.

It seems to me you really need to increase access control so more than just knowing an ID is necessary to update anything.

If you can't do that you can either add a long, random, alphanumeric secondary ID column and use the secondary ID in your output instead of the normal ID, or you could use temporal ID translation tables.

That said, I would still recommend to seriously increasing access control, so people can only update stuff they are allowed to update.